# A question regarding a memory leak in a C++ program

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I received this piece of code as an assignment and one of the questions was: Will there be a memory leak in the program because the destructor of MyList releases the nodes but not the data.
Does the string class release the memory by itself when delete node is performed? And if the template variable is not a string or something else... In short, I can't understand if there is a problem here. What happens when the node memory is released?

```
template<class E> class MyList 
{
    class Node 
    {
        friend class MyList<E>;
        E data;
        Node* next = nullptr;
        ~Node() {  }
    };

    Node* head = new Node;
    Node* tail = head;
    Node* createNode(const E& data, Node* prev)
    {
        Node* node = new Node;
        node->data = data;
        node->next = prev->next;
        prev->next = node;
        return node;
    }
    public:
    MyList() = default;
    MyList(const MyList&) = delete;
    MyList& operator =(const MyList&) = delete;

    void push_front(const E& data) 
    {
        Node* node = createNode(data, head);
        if (tail == head) tail = head;
    }
    void push_back(const E& data)
    {
        tail = createNode(data, tail);
    }

    ~MyList() 
    {
        Node* node = head, * next;
        while (node != nullptr)
        {
            next = node->next;
            delete node;
            node = next;
        }
    }

    template<class Function>
    void apply(Function f)const 
    {
        Node* node = head->next;
        while (node != nullptr)
        {
            f(node->data);
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyList<std::string>m3;
    m3.push_back("Hello");
    m3.push_back("World");
    MyList<MyList<std::string>*> m4;
    m4.push_front(&m3);
    m4.push_back(&m3);
    m4.apply([](auto plist)
    {
        plist->apply([](const auto& val) 
        {
            std::cout << val << std::endl;
        });
    });     
}
```

I can't figure out if when Node is released the features inside it are also released. I would appreciate an answer regarding this.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read due to the lack of indentation.  Please properly format your code to include proper indentation.

Comment: `if (tail == head) tail = head;` is assigning the value that is assumed to be same by the `if` and looks meaningless.

Comment: The function `push_front` (which has the meaningless statement) is not saving the newly created `node` and causing memory leak.

Comment: @MikeCAT I realised. Can you tell me please, does the MyList destructor also have a memory leak?
Regardless of the main one that is listed, i.e. is it correct to release only the nodes without the data inside?

Comment: You shouldn't care what `E` is.  Your `Node` class has no idea if `E` uses dynamically allocated memory or not.  It is the responsibility of the client code to handle any dynamically allocated memory *outside* of your `Node` class, and `std::string` does that job just fine.  Your `Node` class should only concern itself with the memory itself has allocated to maintain the list, and that w3as pointed out by @MikeCAT

Comment: Look at how `std::llst` works.  If I have `std::list<Widget*>`, is isn't the responsibility of `std::list` to figure out where that `Widget*` you are putting in `std::list` comes from, thus cannot blindly call `delete` on the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you very much, I understand what you are saying. Actually E is not my responsibility and I can't just let go.
A more general question - as soon as I execute a destructor on a node, will all the destructors of all the objects contained in the node be activated?

Comment: Side note: When you find yourself writing a function like `createNode`, stop and ask yourself, "Why am I not adding a constructor to `Node` instead? If you have a good answer, and there are good answers, continue writing the create function. If not, write a constructor. With a create function you leave open the possibility of a `Node` being constructed without the create function configuring it correctly and have to debug the results later. If the constructor does all of the configuration, you either have a correctly configured `Node` or you don't have a `Node` at all and no chance of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor for the `MyList` class does not leak memory unless it is the responsibility of `Node` objects to *own* the data any pointer they may contain points to. A node's `data` member will be destroyed when the node is destroyed.

Consider a case like `MyList<int *>` where each element in the list is a pointer to an `int`. We would not expect destroying the list to destroy the original `int` values the nodes' `data` members point to, especially as they may not have been dynamically allocated in the first place.